# Population of Canaan at the time that Bnei Yisrael entered

Tags: eretz-yisrael, canaan

What was the population of Canaan at the time that Bnei Yisrael entered the land to conquer it? I've heard that the population of Bnei Yisrael was ~2 million, and that in some sense of the word, Bnei Yisrael was considered a "small" nation (e.g. as mentioned in Parashat Va'etchanan). Could it be that each of the 7 nations inhabiting the land were larger than Bnei Yisrael, resulting in a net population greater than 14 million?

Comment: Relevant: in Shemos 23:29 and Devarim 7:22, Hashem says that if the Canaanites would be eradicated too quickly, wild animals would take over the land. If anyone can find demographic studies that suggest a factor by which a human population needs to go down for wild or feral animals to invade the area, that could give us some idea.